# PHP catch a failed include

Tags: php, exception, include, try-catch

I'm trying to include a file, and catch it if the file does not exist / can not be opened. I would have thought that a simple try/catch statement would have worked but PHP seems to completely ignore it, and error out.

Any ideas? I know there are other questions like this on stackoverflow, I've seen them, but none of them seem to have a proper, working answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can check the return value of include to see if it failed or not:

```
if((@include $filename) === false)
{
    // handle error
}
```

You'll note I included the error suppression operator (`@` ) to hide the standard error messages from being displayed.

Comment: using @ is a very dirty solution

Comment: I think using @, the error control operator is perfectly fine, if you handle the error.  It just makes sure that the nasty include failed error isn't output if the configuration has such warnings turned on.

Comment: Yup, the exact reason I want to do this is to be able to handle the error ;)

Answer (score 5):

Since `include()` returns `false` when fails, just check if it returns true and then do something like `die()` or show an error.

```
if (!include('page.php'))
   die('Error.');
```

Comment: If you're going to `die`, you might as well just use [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) though.

Answer (score 1):

As [Brendan Long's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015457/php-catch-a-failed-include#comment17227061_8015496) points out, if you're just wanting the script to stop running on a failed `include`, then you probably just want to be using [`require`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) instead.